# Deleting Entity with OneToMany Relationship With Another Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have two tables. These are Design and Like. One design can have many likes and one like should be related to one Design.

When I try to delete a Design it throws me an exception:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_dbo.DesignLike_dbo.Design_DesignId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "XXXDB", table "dbo.DesignLike", column 'DesignId'. The
>   statement has been terminated.

modelBuilder.Entity().HasMany(x => x.Likes).WithRequired(x => x.Design).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

I dont even try to delete related entities ? Why I get this exception ?

Comment: you cannot delete a parent entry unless all the child entries are deleted. if you want to delete them as well than set it to .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to delete an object that still has child objects. And the foreign key on the child objects will give you this exception.

You should decouple the child objects are link them to another parent before deleting the current one. Or include them in a cascaded delete.

In your case the design you are trying to delete has at least one like with the foreign key set to the id of your design. When you now delete the design and cascading is off it will violate the foreign key constraint of your like.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've set up your database to enforce a valid foreign key constraint on the `DesignId` column in your `DesignLike` table.

If you try and delete a `Design`, you're deleting the `DesignId` which is referenced by all the `DesignLikes` as a foreign key. If you were allowed to do that, you'd find your database in an inconsistent state - your foreign key wouldn't really have meaning if there isn't a guarantee it references a valid record.

You could either remove the now invalid foreign key from your child objects, or set add a `Deleted` / `Visible` flag to your `Design` if you wish keep the `Design` and corresponding `DesignLikes`